# LESS: Extend a previously defined nested selector

Tags: css, compilation, less, extend

I've been trying like a mad man to get the following LESS statement to work, but now i am fearing that it's not gonna happen :/ So I am turning now to you guys in the end for help!

I have the following statement:

```
.top{
    &-first{
        background:black;
        &-item{
            color:white;
        }
    }
    &-second{
        background:green;
        &-item:extend(.top-first-item){}
    }
}
```

I was hoping for to achive the following output:

```
.top-first {
    background: black;
}
.top-first-item,
.top-second-item{
    color: white;
}
.top-second {
    background: green;
}
```

**But unfortunately it does not compile that but this instead:**

```
.top-first {
    background: black;
}
.top-first-item{
    color: white;
}
.top-second {
    background: green;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LESS currently does not support extending a "concatenated name" selectors (basically, `.top &-first &-item` is interpreted as three distinct selector elements and never found by `extend` looking for a single selector).

A workaround for your particular case:

```
.top {
    &-first {
        background: black;
    }

    &-second {
        background: green;
    }

    &-first, &-second {
        &-item {
            color: white;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So far this will have to do! But the https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1597 issue here really should be fixed!

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to break the designations into separate classes:

**LESS**

```
.top{
    &.first{
        background:black;
        &.item{
            color:white;
        }
    }
    &.second{
        background:green;
        &.item:extend(.top.first.item){}
    }
}
```

**CSS Output**

```
.top.first {
  background: black;
}
.top.first.item,
.top.second.item {
  color: white;
}
.top.second {
  background: green;
}
```

***Which of course requires a change in your html designation*** from `class="top-first-item"` to `class="top first item"`.

Comment: unfortunately that would break my css logic, so i can't do that, it should be 1 class to rule them all :P

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously something that should be working in LESS. I have a few months ago put an issue on the LESS.js github regarding exactly this.

[Link to Github issue](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1597)

In the mean time, i recommend using seven-phases-max's solution by simply putting the classes together like so:

```
&-first, &-second {}
```

But then you cant abstract the second out into another file.

Another solution would to make an `"extends.less"` file, in which you can have small snippets you find your self using time from time.

Answer (score -1):

Just use 'all' suffix. Example: &:extend(.top-first-item **all**);

Comment: oh, yes, my mistake, sry