# LESS &:extend not compiling property in Visual Studio with Web Essentials 4

Tags: visual-studio-2013, less, web-essentials

This is my first question and I tried to search first but couldn't find the answer.

I am using Web Essentials 4 in MS Visual Studio to compile LESS files to CSS.

It works fine, but recently I wanted to try using the &:extend functionality of LESS, but it won't compile correctly. It just ignores the &:extend part.

So I have a simple .less file, with this code:

```
#em-main {
  nav ul {
    &:extend(.inline);
    background: blue;
  }
  .inline {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

And this is the output.

```
#em-main nav ul {
  background: blue;
}
#em-main .inline {
  color: red;
}
```

If I take out the #em-main, it compiles fine. Is this a limitation of LESS or is something wrong with my setup?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if possible what you try to do. In fact you try to extend `#em-main .inline` which is not possible, see also: [LESS: Extend a previously defined nested selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20091264/less-extend-a-previously-defined-nested-selector), https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/1597 and so on.

Possible use a mixin or a ruleset:

```
@set-color: {
color: red;
};

#em-main {
  nav ul {
    @set-color();
    background: blue;
  }
  .inline {
    @set-color();
  }
}
```

** update **

the above compiles into:

```
#em-main nav ul {
  color: red;
  background: blue;
}
#em-main .inline {
  color: red;
}
```

But now @harry wrotes:

> I think using :extend(#em-main .inline) (full selector path) would
>   also work.

And he is right (of course);

```
#em-main {
  nav ul {
    &:extend(#em-main .inline);
    background: blue;
  }
  .inline {
    color: red;
  }
}
```

compiles into

```
#em-main nav ul {
  background: blue;
}
#em-main .inline,
#em-main nav ul {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: I think using `:extend(#em-main .inline)` (full selector path) would also work.

Comment: Thank guys, can't believe I didn't think of that :) :)