# Extend function doesn't work with nested selectors

Tags: css, less, extend

I have some problems with Less' `extend` function. In some cases it doesn't work and I can't figure out why. There is a piece of problematic code:

```
.page-header {
    .bar:extend(.fixedElement) { // it works
        ...
    }
    .menu:extend(.fixedElement) { // it works
        ...
    }
    // some other stuff
    .menu-list {
        ...
        .btnStyle {
            padding: 18px 20px;
            min-height: 60px;
            width: 100%;
            display: block;
            border-bottom: 1px solid @light2;
        }
        .linkStyle:extend(.btnStyle) { // doesn't work
            //.btnStyle;
            background-color: @light1;
            .remCalc(14);
            &:active {
                background-color: transparent;
            }
        }
        .chosen {
            background-color: transparent;
            &:after {
                color: @primaryColor;
            }
        }
        ...
        .level-2 {
            & > ul {
                a:extend(.linkStyle) { // doesn't work
                    //.linkStyle;
                }
            }
        }
        .level-3 {
            ...
            & > ul > li {
                .btn-menu {
                    &.shown:extend(.chosen) { // doesn't work
                        //.chosen;
                    }
                }
                & > a:extend(.linkStyle) { // doesn't work
                    //.linkStyle;
                }
            }
            .selected {
                .btn-menu:extend(.chosen) { // doesn't work
                    //.chosen;
                }
            }
        }
        .btn-menu:extend(.btnStyle) { // doesn't work
            //.btnStyle;
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

And:

```
.gradientBg {
    background: rgb(200, 200, 200);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(295deg, rgb(200, 200, 200) 10%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 90%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(295deg, rgb(200, 200, 200) 10%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 90%);
    background: linear-gradient(25deg, rgb(200, 200, 200) 10%, rgb(255, 255, 255) 90%);
    border: 1px solid @light2;
}

.gr-box, .btn-1 {
    &:extend(.gradientBg); //it works
}
```

Elements extended by `.fixedElement` or `.gradientBg` compile to CSS normally, but not these with `.btnStyle`, `.linkStyle` and `.chosen` (they just aren't in CSS; now it works only by every time placed mixins). There aren't any errors during compilation.

I use Brackets 1.3 with Less Autocompile 1.1.9 extension. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For extend to work, you need to specify an exactly matching selector in full (like `&:extend(.page-header .menu-list .btnStyle)`).

Comment: **Note:** I have added a detailed answer because I couldn't find an exact dupe for this one. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20091264/less-extend-a-previously-defined-nested-selector) is not an exact dupe even though the name might suggest so.

Comment: @Harry, Yep, I was already thinking of suggesting you to write an answer since there's definitely no such answer at SO yet (some topic cover this of course but none are solely dedicated). So good work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Reason:

> **Quoting [Less Website](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature-extending-nested-selectors):** <sup>emphasis is mine</sup>
>
> Extend by default looks for **exact match between selectors**. It does matter whether selector uses leading star or not. It does not matter that two nth-expressions have the same meaning, they need to have to same form in order to be matched. The only exception are quotes in attribute selector, less knows they have the same meaning and matches them.

The following would work because the parameter to the `extend` function exactly matches another selector that is already defined. (**Note:** I have removed some properties to keep it simple.)

```css
.gradientBg { background: rgb(200, 200, 200); }
.gr-box, .btn-1 { &:extend(.gradientBg); }
```

But the below would not work because the compiled selector path of the nested selector would be `.parent .gradientBg` and the parameter provided to the `extend` function is not an exact match.

```css
.parent{
  .gradientBg { background: rgb(200, 200, 200); }
}
.gr-box, .btn-1 { &:extend(.gradientBg); }
```

Less compiler **would not even throw an error** in the above scenario because it fails silently when there is no match.

---

### Solution:

When using `extend` feature to extend nested selectors, an exactly matching selector (full selector path) should be provided (or) the `all` keyword should be used.

The below would work as the full matching selector path is provided to the `extend` function.

```css
.parent{
  .gradientBg { background: rgb(200, 200, 200); }
}
.gr-box, .btn-1 { &:extend(.parent .gradientBg); }
```

Or, depending on your needs even this would work because the `all` keyword is used.

```css
.parent{
  .gradientBg { background: rgb(200, 200, 200); }
}
.gr-box, .btn-1 { &:extend(.gradientBg all); }
```

---

But note how the output selector has the structure `.parent .gr-box` and `.parent .btn-1`. This is because Less replaces **only the matched part of the selector with the new selector**. In `.parent .gradientBg` (original selector), the matched part (provided as parameter to `extend`) is only `.gradientBg` and hence the output selector after `extend` would be `.parent .gr-box`.

> Here is what the Less website says about **extend "all":** <sup>emphasis is mine</sup>
>
> When you specify the all keyword last in an extend argument it tells Less to match that selector as part of another selector. The selector will be copied **and the matched part of the selector only will then be replaced with the extend**, making a new selector.

Another thing that should also be noted when using `all` keyword is that, Less would extend properties of all selectors that have a matching part. So, for example if we consider the below Less code.

```css
.parent{
  .gradientBg { background: rgb(200, 200, 200); }
}
.parent2{
  .gradientBg{ color: red; }
}
.gr-box, .btn-1 { &:extend(.gradientBg all); }
```

the output would be as follows because `.gradientBg` selector is used both within `.parent` and `.parent2`.

```css
.parent .gradientBg, .parent .gr-box, .parent .btn-1 {
  background: #c8c8c8;
}
.parent2 .gradientBg, .parent2 .gr-box, .parent2 .btn-1 {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Btw., currently (since v2.2.x or so) the compiler emits a warning if `extend` is not matched (but whether you'll see it or not depends on the actual tool you use to compile, by the moment most of the tools except `lessc` itself notify only of errors).