# Extending a class within a nested class - LESS

Tags: css, less

Is there a way to mixin a class within a class in LESS?

```
block {
  &__element {
    &--modifier-one {
       color: red;
    }
    &--modifier--two {
       &:extend(--modifier-one); // this is what I'm trying to do
    }
  }
}
```

The expected output is:

```
block__element--modifier-one {
    color: red;
}
block__element--modifier-two {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: what you wrote as expected output would be completely new classes (different name) which have nothing to do with the original ones - is that your intention? Or do you want a css selector that applies only to elements which have all three classes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LESS: Extend a previously defined nested selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20091264/less-extend-a-previously-defined-nested-selector)